# Count Categorical Variables Summarized by Month and Year

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I am attempting to summarize a count of categorical variables by month and year.  Below shows what I obtain versus what I desire.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data <- tibble(Date = as.Date(c("2021-10-01", "2021-10-01", "2021-10-01", "2022-10-01")),
               b = c("honey", "honey", "free", "love"))
               
data

# A tibble: 4 × 2
#  Date       b    
#  <date>     <chr>
#1 2021-10-01 honey
#2 2021-10-01 honey
#3 2021-10-01 free 
#4 2022-10-01 love
```

The code:

```
data %>% group_by(year=year(Date), month=month(Date)) %>% count()
```

Produces this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   year, month [2]
#   year month     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1  2021    10     3
# 2  2022    10     1
```

But this is what I desire as output ...

```
#    year month   honey   free    love
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <int>  <int>   <int>
# 1  2021    10       2      1       0
# 2  2022    10       0      0       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_wider()` with the `values_fn` (to count how many occurrences using `length`) and `values_fill` (to replace `NA` values with 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = b, 
              values_from = b, 
              values_fn = length,
              values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
 Date       honey  free  love
  <date>     <int> <int> <int>
1 2021-10-01     2     1     0
2 2022-10-01     0     0     1
```

If you want to add `month` in there, just use a simple `mutate` after pivoting:

```
data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = b, 
              values_from = b, 
              values_fn = length,
              values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date))
```

Output:

```
 Date       honey  free  love month
  <date>     <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 2021-10-01     2     1     0    10
2 2022-10-01     0     0     1    10
```